# Owin AAD - required parameters for signature validation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, katana, adal

I playing with webapi and trying to setup app configuration for proper signature validation in
**WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions**

I have noticed **MetadataAddress** field is not used in several examples online and in AAD auth samples: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-WebAPI-MultiTenant-WindowsStore/blob/master/TodoListServiceMT/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

When I launch the app I noticed there is a request to  https://login.windows.net/common/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml on app launch even though the field is not set. Is this the default value to MetadataAddress?

- How does the signature validation work even though the sts address is
  different in token?
- How is the validation handled in case of custom sts service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tenant parameter passed in the option is enough for the middleware to determine the location of the metadata document of the corresponding Azure AD tenant. In the case of multitenant applications, as you observed that value is common. In the multitenant sample you can see that there is custom logic that takes over the verification of the issuer (what you called the "sts address" - that's more of an identifier). As you can see in the file that you linked, the options turn off the issuer validation via the switch `ValidateIssuer = false`. If you take a look at https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-WebAPI-MultiTenant-WindowsStore/blob/master/TodoListServiceMT/AuthorizationFilters/MTAuthorizeAttribute.cs, you'll see that it executes logic meant to compare the issuer in the incoming token against a list of trusted issuer. Your own application might have different business logic for establishing whether the issuer of the incoming token should be trusted.

Comment: Thanks. How is the validation handled in case of custom issuer/sts service?

Comment: You mean not from azure ad? It will depend on whatever mechanism you use for acquiring auth info from your custom sts.

Comment: For custom issuer, does sts claim in token point to right location from where you get the signing token.

Comment: A custom issuer can literally do whatever... But in the azure ad case, that is not the case. As I mentioned above, the issuer claims holds an identifier - that does not necessarily correspond to a network addressable endpoint and in the case of azure ad it doesn't